# How to obtain buildings base (Ground) Height from Esri Terrain Dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, terrain

How can I join Height data (surface, DTM) from [terrain dataset](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0311/terrain-datasets.html) to buildings polygons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to spatial analyst extension, you can use [Zonal Statistic as Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000w8000000.htm) tool.  It will create a table of various statistics that fall within you building polygons.  These values can be joined to your polygon shape based on the building feature ID.

Comment: thanks, but Terrain Dataset is not a raster and it can't be input for zonal statistic

Comment: Convert TIN to Raster, http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q900000077000000

Comment: Thanks,  but Terrain Dataset is not a TIN and it can't be input for tin to raster

Comment: What about [Terrain To Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q90000002t000000)?

Comment: Thanks That will do it. I Can All so Spatially Join The LiDAR Mass Points to the Buildings...

Comment: With zonal stats tools, you can calculate mean, median, sum, max, min, etc.  FYI in case that helps you.

Comment: @Geog Were you able to solve your problem with the answer provided?